# Sticking Foundation footer to the bottom of page

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, frontend

I'm new to foundation framework and am having trouble having my footer stay fixed to the bottom of the page regardless of window size. I've used the footer class? What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
.wrapper
  .row.footer
    .small-12.columns.small-centered
      %ul.inline-list
        %li
          = link_to "GitHub", "http://www.github.com/XXXX"
        %li
          %span x
        %li
          = link_to "LinkedIn", "http://www.linkedin.com/in/XXXX"
        %li
          %span x
        %li
          = link_to "Facebook", "http://www.facebook.com/XXXX"
        %li
          %span x
        %li
          = link_to "Instagram", "http://www.instagram.com/XXXX"
```

CSS:

```
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both; /*Why does this work?*/

  ul {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 100px;
  }

  .inline-list {
    height: 75px;
  }
}
```

application.css:

```
*, html {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: You can use this CSS

```
.footer{position:fixed; bottom:0; z-index:100000}
```

but depending on your content, it may add some additional issues when viewing on different devices, so I'd also recommend to check https://github.com/coreysyms/foundationStickyFooter which does a re-calculation of screen size for a bullet proof footer